# Как сделать таймер который будет длится 10 секунд и обновлять сообщение, с функцией bot.wait_for (Discord.Py Python)

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Хочу чтобы мой бот с функцией `bot.wait_for()` обновлял свое сообщение Embed в течении 10 секунд, чтобы было видно сколько времени осталось до ответа. Как это сделать?

```
emb = discord.Embed(
    title='Угадайте страну по флагу!',
    description=f'Флаг: {flag}\nОсталось времени: {duration} секунд',
    color=discord.Colour.green()
)
msg = await ctx.send(embed=emb)

def check(m: discord.Message):

    if mode == 'private':
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
    elif mode == 'public':
        return m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
    else:
        return m.channel.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
    
            

try:
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = check, timeout = time)
```

Тут часть кода и мне надо обновлять Embed-сообщение (`переменная emb`) примерно 10 секунд, т.е. чтобы он показывал сколько времени осталось до того, как кто-то ответит на сообщение бота.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать что-то такое

```py
emb = discord.Embed(
    title='Угадайте страну по флагу!',
    description=f'Флаг: {flag}\nОсталось времени: {duration} секунд',
    color=discord.Colour.green()
)
msg = await ctx.send(embed=emb)

def check(m: discord.Message):
    if mode == 'private':
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
    elif mode == 'public':
        return m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
    else:
        return m.channel.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id

async def update_embed():
    emb.description = f'Флаг: {flag}\nОсталось времени: {duration} секунд'
    await msg.edit(embed=emb)
while duration > 0:
    await update_embed()
    duration -= 1
    time.sleep(1)


try:
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = check, timeout = time)
```

Comment: спасибо большое